# How to make Eloquent model attribute updatable only through public methods?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, eloquent, laravel-7

I want to prevent a model attribute from being directly set from an outside source without going through setters that control the logic.

```
class Person extends Model
{
    public function addMoney($amount)
    {
        if ($amount <= 0) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid amount');
        }
        $this->money += $amount;
    }

    public function useMoney($amount)
    {
        if ($amount > $this->money) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid funds');
        }
        $this->money -= $amount;
    }
}
```

This should not be allowed:

```
$person->money = -500;
```

You must use some kind of accessor or setter method:

```
$person->useMoney(100);
```

But I don't care how you get the value:

```
echo $person->money;
// or
echo $person->getMoney();
// whatever
```

How do I enforce that the only way to update this attribute would be through specific methods that dictate some additional logic? In a sense, make a model attribute private or protected.

I want to do this separately and/or before the model data is persisted to the database.

Comment: I don't think that's the correct place to add that sort of validation. Instead I think using a validator to validate the user input before enacting the change on the model would be the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the set..Attribute() function for each member variable you want to protect,
or you could potentially perform your validation inside the set..Attribute() function rather then having separate public methods.

```
class Person extends Model
{
    public function addMoney($amount)
    {
        if ($amount <= 0) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid amount');
        }

        if (!isset($this->attributes['money'])) {
            $this->attributes['money'] = $amount;
        } else {
            $this->attributes['money'] += $amount;
        }
    }

    public function useMoney($amount)
    {
        if ($amount > $this->money) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid funds');
        }

        if (!isset($this->attributes['money'])) {
            $this->attributes['money'] = -$amount;
        } else {
            $this->attributes['money'] -= $amount;
        }
    }

    public function setMoneyAttribute($val) {
        throw new \Exception('Do not access ->money directly, See addMoney()');
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried something like this already, but the class itself cannot modify the attributes either if you override `setAttribute()`.

Comment: good point, i have updated the answer, so that it will work. by referencing the attributes directly when used internally in the class via the $attributes field

Comment: I did try that as well. It was just giving me a "Undefined index" exception for the attribute.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Not sure why I presumed I couldn't set up the attribute manually myself. Still not sure I actually like my original idea for this question, but your solution does work.

Comment: Yeah it seems a little counter-intuitive to how models generally work. You could do a separate class that manipulates the model and perform validation in there. Eg $money_service->useMoney($model, $amount), although at the end of the day, whatever is simplest and easiest for you to understand is best

Answer (score 0):

Use [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators) and your code should look like this:

```
class Person extends Model
{
    public function setMoneyAttribute($amount)
    {
        if ($amount < 0) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid amount');
        }
        $this->attributes['money'] = $amount;
        $this->save();
    }

   public function addMoney($amount)
    {
        if ($amount <= 0) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid amount');
        }
        $this->money += $amount;
    }

    public function useMoney($amount)
    {
        if ($amount > $this->money) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid funds');
        }
        $this->money -= $amount;
    }
}
```

Now, you can use $person->money = -500 and it will throw an exception. Hope this helps.